# uint8_t to Struct in C

Tags: c, struct, stm32, uart

I'm using an STM32 microcontroller, and I'm receiving data through a UART. I want to convert the received data into a Mesaj structure for further processing. Currently, I'm collecting the data into a buffer (RxBuffer), and I'm wondering how I can convert this data into the 'Mesaj' structure. Here's the part of the code:

```
#define RxBufferSize 50
uint8_t RxBuffer[RxBufferSize];
typedef struct {
    uint8_t baslangic;
    uint16_t emirNo;
    uint8_t birimNo;
    uint32_t emirAdresi;
    uint8_t komut;
    uint8_t dataTipi;
    uint32_t data;
    uint8_t bitis;
} Mesaj;
```

**MORE DETAİL**: I'm receiving RxBuffer in the code snippet below and I want to process it, but first, I'd like to convert it into the struct after checking the size of RxBuffer.

```
void HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint16_t Size)
{
    if (huart->Instance == USART1)
    {
        HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_DMA(&huart1, RxBuffer, RxBufferSize);
        __HAL_DMA_DISABLE_IT(&hdma_usart1_rx, DMA_IT_HT);
            
              for (int i = Size; i < RxBufferSize; i++)
        {
            RxBuffer[i] = 0;
        }
                            
        if (Size == 15) 
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You need to know the byte order of the 16- and 32-bit fields in the buffer.

Comment: You could convert the data many, many different ways.  But only a very small fraction of those, at most, are *correct*, and you haven't given us any way to determine which.  We need to know how to interpret the byte sequence, which is primarily a function of how the sender organized things.

Comment: I think you may also define a union and automatically get received data structured

Answer (score 3):

Use `memcpy`:

```
Mesaj *buffToStuct(Mesaj *m, void *buff, size_t offset)
{
    unsigned char *ucbuff = buff;
    memcpy(m, ucbuff + offset, sizeof(*m));
    return m;
}
```

Remember that the format of has to be the same as the struct (padding, endianess etc).

If the input stream does not have padding pack the structure:

```
typedef struct {
    uint8_t baslangic;
    uint16_t emirNo;
    uint8_t birimNo;
    uint32_t emirAdresi;
    uint8_t komut;
    uint8_t dataTipi;
    uint32_t data;
    uint8_t bitis;
} __attribute__((packed)) Mesaj;
```

Comment: Additional advice: when using packed structs, watch data alignment. Various processors (varies even within STM) handle unaligned accesses differently, from having no problem at all (at the expense of memory access speed), and all the way to hardfaulting. Best to organize data in such a way, that everything is always aligned. For example, `uint32_t data` in the struct can become 16-bit aligned, not 32-bit aligned. `uint16_t emirNo` could also easily end up being unaligned.

Comment: @Ilya when compiler knows that the struct is packed - it will generate the correct instructions to avoid HFs. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/z4PEx5Grn

Comment: Interesting. I think I had some problems with it at some point. Maybe because it was configured to work with device that supports native unaligned access like (at least) some M4. Important to note tho that FPU in STM32 does not support unaligned access even if it works for integers. No floats here, but just in case.

Comment: @Ilya it is not an issue as well as compiler knows it very well https://godbolt.org/z/sEvoYosEE

Comment: @Ilya or https://godbolt.org/z/jnTMhexnK

Comment: I guess my remarks are only relevant for assembly programming. That was enlightening.